# Predicting the number of orders from future customers

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

> Tamara is reviewing recent orders at her deli to determine which meats she should order. She found that of 1,000 orders, 450 customers ordered turkey, 375 customers ordered ham and 250 customers ordered neither turkey nor ham. Based on data, how many of the next 1,000 customers will order both turkey and ham?

Do I use a two way table? Or what is the function. I am honestly not clear on what to do. Can someone explain it to me, please? I would put the work I've done, but it's scribbled on a paper and absolutely wrong. Thank you

Comment: About the wording: you say 1000 customers and 1000 orders. Does each customer place exactly one order? Is one order only for a specific type of meat, or can a customer order multiple types in one order?

Comment: I am assuming so, this is the exact wording that i was given ;/

Answer (score 1):

We'll denote "neither turkey nor ham" as NTNH.

We had $1000$ orders. We'll subtract the $250$ orders for NTNH: we had $750$ orders for turkey or ham. (We are using the inclusive *or* here.) $450$ customers ordered turkey and $375$ ordered ham. $450+375 = 825$, and $825-750=75$. So it follows that $75$ customers ordered both ham and turkey, else we are somehow overcounting. So if out of $1000$ customers, $75$ ordered both ham and turkey, then we can expect that of the next $1000$ customers, the same will happen: $75$ will order both ham and turkey.